# Add class to parent based on childelements link url

Tags: jquery

I want to use .addClass to give my li element a class based on the url of the a element. How do I achieve this with jQuery?

```
<li><a href="/m4n?seid=etailer-orderhistorylist">Tidigare ordrar</a></li>
```

Comment: according to given html what must be the class name for <li> based on url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify this href in a selector and use jQuery `parent()` and `addClass()`:

```
$("a[href='/m4n?seid=etailer-orderhistorylist']").parent().addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. Hope this will help you.

```
$('li > a').each(function () {
    if (this.href == '/m4n?seid=etailer-orderhistorylist') {
        $(this).parent().addClass('your_class');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to put `<a>s` content(text) as a class of `<li>` and if thats the case.

```
$("a").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass($(this).text());
});
```